# MongoDB startup errors

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, database-connection, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to migrate from my Ubuntu server. When I tried to start MongoDB in the new environment which is a Windows 10 Ubuntu 18 bash subsystem:

```
mongod --dbpath ./mongoData
```

I received the following errors:

```
2019-01-07T11:41:33.981+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2166 port=27017 dbpath=/mnt/d/QuizJungle/mongoData 64-bit host=PHANG
2019-01-07T11:41:33.982+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.9
2019-01-07T11:41:33.983+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 167861a164723168adfaaa866f310cb94010428f
2019-01-07T11:41:33.983+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-01-07T11:41:33.983+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-01-07T11:41:33.984+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-01-07T11:41:33.984+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-01-07T11:41:33.985+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-01-07T11:41:33.985+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/mnt/d/QuizJungle/mongoData" } }
2019-01-07T11:41:33.988+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=64863M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),cache_cursors=false,compatibility=(release="3.0",require_max="3.0"),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-01-07T11:41:34.496+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (5) [1546832494:496438][2166:0x7f3f529f0a40], connection: __posix_sync, 108: /mnt/d/QuizJungle/mongoData/: directory-sync: fdatasync: Input/output error
2019-01-07T11:41:34.496+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1546832494:496615][2166:0x7f3f529f0a40], connection: __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2019-01-07T11:41:34.497+0800 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28558 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 376
2019-01-07T11:41:34.498+0800 F -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure


2019-01-07T11:41:34.515+0800 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x7f3f54c25811 0x7f3f54c24a29 0x7f3f54c24f0d 0x7f3f517f2890 0x7f3f5141ee97 0x7f3f51420801 0x7f3f533a6886 0x7f3f5347124e 0x7f3f534e2511 0x7f3f5334489e 0x7f3f53344cbe 0x7f3f534ac4c3 0x7f3f534ac662 0x7f3f534acfdb 0x7f3f534a9620 0x7f3f53504436 0x7f3f534c7c47 0x7f3f534a65ae 0x7f3f5348298e 0x7f3f53452f8e 0x7f3f53437404 0x7f3f5363ade7 0x7f3f533403a8 0x7f3f53416ffc 0x7f3f533a8549 0x7f3f51401b97 0x7f3f534069b1
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"2200811","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"21FFA29"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"21FFF0D"},{"b":"7F3F517E0000","o":"12890"},{"b":"7F3F513E0000","o":"3EE97","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F3F513E0000","o":"40801","s":"abort"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"981886","s":"_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"A4C24E"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"ABD511"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"91F89E","s":"__wt_err_func"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"91FCBE","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"A874C3"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"A87662"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"A87FDB"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"A84620","s":"__wt_open"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"ADF436","s":"__wt_block_manager_create"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"AA2C47","s":"__wt_schema_create"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"A815AE","s":"__wt_turtle_init"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"A5D98E","s":"wiredtiger_open"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"A2DF8E","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mbbbb"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"A12404"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"C15DE7","s":"_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"91B3A8"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"9F1FFC","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"983549","s":"main"},{"b":"7F3F513E0000","o":"21B97","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"7F3F52A25000","o":"9E19B1"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.6.9", "gitVersion" : "167861a164723168adfaaa866f310cb94010428f", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-17134-Microsoft", "version" : "#345-Microsoft Wed Sep 19 17:47:00 PST 2018", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "7F3F52A25000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2B0D1BCE9C6C49B9246DD60788791DE608E88305" }, { "b" : "7FFFDC8AD000", "path" : "linux-vdso.so.1", "elfType" : 3 }, { "b" : "7F3F523E0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "390E9CC4C215314B6D8ADE6D6E28F8518418039C" }, { "b" : "7F3F521D0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9826FBDF57ED7D6965131074CB3C08B1009C1CD8" }, { "b" : "7F3F51FC0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "25AD56E902E23B490A9CCDB08A9744D89CB95BCC" }, { "b" : "7F3F51C20000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A33761AB8FB485311B3C85BF4253099D7CABE653" }, { "b" : "7F3F51A00000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "92E0BE1929D28508CF9C6D5754C7EB48C12255B3" }, { "b" : "7F3F517E0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "28C6AADE70B2D40D1F0F3D0A1A0CAD1AB816448F" }, { "b" : "7F3F513E0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B417C0BA7CC5CF06D1D1BED6652CEDB9253C60D0" }, { "b" : "7F3F52600000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "64DF1B961228382FE18684249ED800AB1DCEAAD4" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x7f3f54c25811]
 mongod(+0x21FFA29) [0x7f3f54c24a29]
 mongod(+0x21FFF0D) [0x7f3f54c24f0d]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f3f517f2890]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0xC7) [0x7f3f5141ee97]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7f3f51420801]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj+0x0) [0x7f3f533a6886]
 mongod(+0xA4C24E) [0x7f3f5347124e]
 mongod(+0xABD511) [0x7f3f534e2511]
 mongod(__wt_err_func+0x90) [0x7f3f5334489e]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x3F) [0x7f3f53344cbe]
 mongod(+0xA874C3) [0x7f3f534ac4c3]
 mongod(+0xA87662) [0x7f3f534ac662]
 mongod(+0xA87FDB) [0x7f3f534acfdb]
 mongod(__wt_open+0x4A0) [0x7f3f534a9620]
 mongod(__wt_block_manager_create+0x66) [0x7f3f53504436]
 mongod(__wt_schema_create+0x4A7) [0x7f3f534c7c47]
 mongod(__wt_turtle_init+0x3CE) [0x7f3f534a65ae]
 mongod(wiredtiger_open+0x1B8E) [0x7f3f5348298e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mbbbb+0x8BE) [0x7f3f53452f8e]
 mongod(+0xA12404) [0x7f3f53437404]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x637) [0x7f3f5363ade7]
 mongod(+0x91B3A8) [0x7f3f533403a8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_+0x86C) [0x7f3f53416ffc]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x7f3f533a8549]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xE7) [0x7f3f51401b97]
 mongod(+0x9E19B1) [0x7f3f534069b1]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
Aborted (core dumped)
```

/mongoData/ is just an empty directory. I tried doing a disk scan for bad sectors but no errors were found.

What should I do to start the MongoDB server successfully?

Comment: have you found a solution for your problem? I had the same error :s

Comment: It has been some time. I can't remember what I did to run it. I think I switched to a different version of MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how you reached this state. Things like creating your data directory with incorrect permissions would have errored out differently. I suspect it has something to do with how you migrated between platforms. How did you migrate, and yet use an empty data directory?

**My recommendation would be to use a newer version of the database if creating a new collection/database because 3.6.x is quite old, almost 5 years at this point. 6.0 was released this summer.**

With that being said, you can drill into the error output. Take a look at this line:

```
2019-01-07T11:41:34.496+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (5) [1546832494:496438][2166:0x7f3f529f0a40], connection: __posix_sync, 108: /mnt/d/QuizJungle/mongoData/: directory-sync: fdatasync: Input/output error
```

This indicates that WiredTiger, the storage engine, had an I/O error. Specifically, a system call to `fdatasync()` returned `108`.

WiredTiger has this to say about failed `fdatasync()` calls:

```
* __posix_sync --
*   Underlying support function to flush a file descriptor.
*
* Fsync calls (or fsync-style calls, for example, fdatasync) are not retried
* on failure, and failure halts the system.
*
* Excerpted from the LWN.net article https://lwn.net/Articles/752063/:
* In short, PostgreSQL assumes that a successful call to fsync() indicates
* that all data written since the last successful call made it safely to
* persistent storage. But that is not what the kernel actually does. When
* a buffered I/O write fails due to a hardware-level error, filesystems
* will respond differently, but that behavior usually includes discarding
* the data in the affected pages and marking them as being clean. So a read
* of the blocks that were just written will likely return something other
* than the data that was written.
*
* Given the shared history of UNIX filesystems, and the difficulty of knowing
* what specific error will be returned under specific circumstances, we don't
* retry fsync-style calls and panic if a flush operation fails.
```

These error codes are system-specific, so you can look it up on your system by grepping your system headers, or by using a utility in `moreutils`. In my case, on Ubuntu 18.04, this translates to `ESHUTDOWN`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install moreutils
$ errno -l | grep 108
ESHUTDOWN 108 Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
```